# How can I copy the faces of a window's mode-line to its header-line?

Tags: faces, mode-line, header-line

I want to move my mode-line to the top of each window. So, I've copied its contents into the header-line.

```
(setq-default header-line-format mode-line-format)
(setq-default mode-line-format nil)
```

But, I'm using the modus themes, so the selected window's mode-line shows with different faces.

How can I copy the faces of a window's mode-line to its header-line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Customize face `header-line`, to make it inherit from face `mode-line`.

**`M-x customize-face header-line`**

You can do the same with face `header-line-highlight`, inheriting from face `mode-line-highlight`.

Actually, such face inheritance is done by default.  But some other face attributes are also set by default. You can undefine (unselect) those.

[image]